# Import HEVC video from iPhone 7 to Final Cut Pro

Tags: video, iphone, ios

The video format in iPhone 7, new iOS 11, changed to HEVC and will not show up in Final Cut Pro browser. Can not drag from Photos to FCPX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution until Apple release the next version of Final Cut Pro X is to not shoot in HEVC, or convert before moving to FCP.

> If you haven’t yet shot video you need to edit with FCP, there’s an
>   easy fix.
>
> - Go into the phone’s Settings and choose Camera. Then choose Formats.
>     There you’ll find two options. By default, High Efficiency will be
>     checked. You want to check Most Compatible.
>
> If you have existing HEVC footage you need to edit in FCP, there’s a
>   slightly less easy workaround.
>
> - Import the clip into the Photos app on your Mac. Then, once it’s fully
>     imported (which could take a little while depending on how much video
>     we’re talking about here), then just select the clip(s) you need and
>     Export them from Photos. Photos will export them with a codec that
>     Final Cut Pro X can read. So once the clip(s) is/are exported from
>     Photos to whatever location you chose, then open Final Cut Pro and
>     import the clip(s) you just exported from Photos.

Source: [You can’t yet edit iOS 11 iPhone video in FCP X, fix likely coming soon](https://9to5mac.com/2017/09/29/final-cut-pro-x-h-265-high-efficiency-codec/)

Comment: Note: This does not work on Mac Sierra Photos app. When you try to Import an HEVC-encoded .MOV file, it gives the error *"These items cannot be added to your Photo library because the file format is not supported by Photos."* Sierra Photos also cannot import HEIC images either.

Comment: @wisbucky - Apple released FCP with HEVC support over a year ago [Oct '17, just a week after this QA]. This interim answer is not really valid any more, you now just need to update your macOS/FCP app.